# Joining 2 tables where any of 3 columns in 1 table may match the join column in the second table

Tags: sql, join

There are 2 tables

tblCaller contains the phone numbers of calls received  in a column cCaller.

tblClient contains clients personal details including phone numbers in 3 columns cNumHome, cNumWork and cNumCell.

I need to join the tables to create a recordset so that the personal details of callers can be displayed.

Is a query containing 2 unions the only way to do this?

A redesign of the table is not an option at present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A join might also work:

```
select *
from tblCaller as cal
join tblClient as cli on cal.cCaller = cli.cNumHome or cal.cCaller = cli.cNumWork or cal.cCaller = cli.cNumCell
```